# Disable title translation of YouTube videos

Tags: youtube, languages

Is there any way to prevent the YouTube app from translating (some) video titles from the original title (e.g. English) to the phone's configured language? (e.g. Spanish)

It's really annoying as those translations look auto-generated and are often wrong, and also gives the impression that the video itself is in a different language than the one it is really in.

In YouTube's web interface this does not happen, using the same Google account.

Comment: The simplest workaround I found was to logout. However, the video suggestions shown after logout are generic and kind of useless.

Answer (score 16):

There are many other people, [here](https://support.google.com/youtube/thread/1878493?hl=de) or [here](https://support.google.com/youtube/forum/AAAAiuErobUU1-1wGQgrmY/?hl=en&gpf=%23!topic%2Fyoutube%2FU1-1wGQgrmY) who are looking for the same option. Google has not yet offered a solution to disable the option while on mobile.

Among the possible solutions posted on the second links is to:

> - Go to https://myaccount.google.com/language
> - Add all the languages you understand in the list
> - Reload whatever youtube page you were on
> - Youtube shouldn't translate video titles anymore
>     Note that you may still have some video titles translated for some time because they were cached by your browser.

Also, if you watch videos in languages you don't understand, they will be translated (unless of course you select all languages).

Another possible solution is to change the language of your device to be the same as the language of the video. But it not practical because you will to keep changing languages.

Until Google decides to provide a proper solution, all the above solutions are hit and miss. They work for some and not others.

Comment: I don't know if this worked at some point, but it has no effect now.

Comment: Confirmed, first solution doesn't work. I've got en-us as my primary language, PL as secondary, the problem is still there.

Answer (score 3):

I clicked on my profile picture on youtube and in the menu that breaks I went to languages and set my language to the language of the video in question. That worked for me, hopefully it works for you.

Comment: could you share a screenshot?

Comment: This is NOT a solution. What if there are video in more than one languages? You'll see all titles in your chosen language

Answer (score 0):

You can change it.
Go to You Tube ---> Settings --->Subtitles --->You will be redirect to Google Subtitles(CC) ---> Under regular options you can find Language.
--->And you can choose new default language.

NOTE: In GS(CC) for language options default option is phone default language not Google Acc. language.

Comment: Will the change also apply on the title as well or only subtitles?

Comment: Yes. It will. Basicly title and subtitle are the same in this context

Comment: Thanks, however I changed the subtitle language but it is still the same