# How to stop YouTube from auto-translating the audio of some videos?

Tags: youtube, languages

Now it is possible to add multiple audio files to one video for different languages on YouTube. When I want to listen to an English video, it chooses French audio because I'm French, and I have no way to change that on the Android app.

I changed my location in the settings to the United States, but that didn't change anything. I also set my preferred language to English (United States) in my Google settings, but that didn't change anything either.

How can I listen to the original audio of a video that is not in my native language in the YouTube Android App?

> EDIT: The only solution is to change the language of my phone to the original language of the video I want to listen to, which is very annoying. I would like to know if there is a better way.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. Possibly related to YouTube and localization: [Disable title translation of YouTube videos](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/214537/44325).

Comment: Nope, the only solution is to change the language of my phone to the original language of the video I want to listen to, which is very annoying. @AndrewT.